# ng-class is getting overridden for input tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code

```
<input  type = "text" ng-class = "{'same-method2': true}" />
```

And in CSS,

```
.same-method2 { background-color: #16a085 }
```

But the color does not change. The inspected element has the correct style but is crossed out horizontally.

[image: Inspected Element]

I can use ng-style tag but I can't seem to make it dynamically change colour based on the input.
So why isn't ng-class working for this simple code? What is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means your style is overwritten by another class, or local styles. You have to find the active background or background-color style (you can find it in the inspector) and give it a lower priority than your same-method2 class.

If you want to change the color depending on the input content, you have two solutions:

- either you define one class per color allowed,
- or you use ngStyle

**With classes:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myColor" class="{{myColor}}" />
```

Then, in your CSS:

```
.blue{
    background-color: #222288;
}
```

If you type "blue" in your input, it will become blue.

**With ngStyle:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myColor" ng-style="{ 'background-color': myColor }" />
```

If you type #222288 in your input, it will become blue.

Comment: Hi I get it to work! I put the !important tag next to my CSS and it works. However, I still cannot achieve my goal. My ng-class tag is a conditional statement. For example I want the back ground to change conditionally based on the value of input. It does not seem to change as the value changes. Any idea?

Comment: never use `!important`. It's a huge antipattern. Please check my answer.

Comment: I agree with him, use !important sparingly. I've edited my answer to answer the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class in many ways, if you want it to work conditionally, you can use ternary operator for that like below:

```
 ng-class="myCondition ? 'true-color' : 'false-color'">
```

based on the myCondition it applies 'true-color' class or 'false-color' class

Answer (score 0):

Always the strongest CSS rule will 'win', e.g.: I guess there is another style for the input tag which define a color for that.
Try to use a stronger rule like:

`#mydiv input.same-method { color: #16a085; }`

It should help.